# cannot read state from redux store after routing

Tags: redux, store

my concern is that I cannot read from the redux store after a redirect

```
<Link to="/to/path/:id"></Link>
```

the component is supposed to get the id from the params to read from the state.

this is the error I get after

[image]

this is the **reducer**

I regroup update the state in 1 single location. The list of actions is small for now

```
import { 
  ADD_BOOKING, 
  CONFIRM_BOOKING, 
  ADD_ORDER,
  EDIT_BOOKING
} from "../actions/actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  bookings: [], 
  order: {}
};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === ADD_BOOKING) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      bookings: state.bookings.concat(action.payload)
    });
  }
  if (action.type === EDIT_BOOKING) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      bookings: state.bookings.map(booking => {
        console.log(booking.hotelDetails.id)
        console.log(action.payload.hotelDetails.id)
        if (booking.hotelDetails.id !== action.payload.hotelDetails.id) {
            return booking
        } 
        return Object.assign({}, booking, {
          resaDetails : action.payload.resaDetails
         // booking: action.payload
        })
      })
    })
  }
  if (action.type === ADD_ORDER) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      order: action.payload
    })
  }
  return state;
}
export default rootReducer;
```

this is the **store**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
export default store;
```

this is the **index.js** at the root of the application

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './styles/index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./lib/store/index";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

and this is the file from where I navigate to the path for a specific hotel reservation.
the route is defined like so : "/reservation/:id"

- the id from the params allows me to filter bookings and display hotel reservation with ID
- below, it fails because bookings is null. I cannot read from the state of the store
  [image]

this is the class from where I navigate below. sorry, pasting the code was not working as the format was off.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `store.subscribe` you are already have values in `this.props.bookings` as Array. Also next time reproduce your code in codesandbox or similar environment.